# React-Native: WebView unable to play Youtube video in full screen on android

Tags: android, react-native

I have loads a html page on web viewe, the html page has embedded YouTube url. When this page load on web view and play YouTube video: In iOS it's played in full screen, but in android play only particular area that is defined in HTML. Here is my code,,

```
return (
  <WebView
    source={{uri: property.url}}
    style={styles.webStyle}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    builtInZoomControls={false}
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
    startInLoadingState={true}

  />
);
```

Comment: Same issue here... Any luck?

Comment: No, Still waiting for Answer,,

Comment: @Ashish-Systematix by default on ios the video will use the native player while in android the video will play inline, you need to do a proper implementation that will work on both platforms